# function seg faults instead of returning array

Tags: c, scope, segmentation-fault, return, strtok

I am trying to make a function that returns an array. The array works when i print in the array maker function but when i return it back to the main function it doesn't work.

this is my code:

it seg faults and doesn't return the array correctly.

it works in the array maker function.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `argv` in `arraymaker()` is stored on stack-memory and will destroyed once it gets out of the function's scope.

Comment: A comprehensive article on Stack vs. Heap: https://www.guru99.com/stack-vs-heap.html#:~:text=Stack%20is%20a%20linear%20data,you%20to%20access%20variables%20globally.

Comment: In the C language a function cannot return an array, so you may want to design `arraymaker` a bit differently. How about `size_t arraymaker(const char* input, const char* tokens[], size_t tokensArraySize)`? There is no reason for this function to be ever aware of `Node`, it only splits the input string to tokens. The caller should pass in an array of `char` pointers, which `arraymaker` will fill and return the number of actual tokens found. If `tokensArraySize` is not sufficient to store all the tokens, it should error out somehow (left as an exercise). Avoid magic numbers such as 5 and 10.

Comment: Every time a function returns a pointer to a local variable I imagine it to run away, hide behind a corner, stick fingers into its ears close the eyes - and giggle.

Answer (score 1):

Within the function `arraymaker` you are using the local array `argv` with `5` elements

```
 char * const arraymaker(struct Node* head)
{
        char * pChar;
        char* argv[5];
        //...
```

And the expression in the return statement

```
return argv;
```

has the type `char **`. But the function return type is `char *`.

Moreover you are returning a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function. So the returned pointer will be invalid.

Apart from this in main you are using a loop with the magic number `10` (instead of using at least the number `5`) and as the pointer declared as having the type `const char *` then the expression `commands[i]` have the type `char` that you are trying to output using the conversion specifier `s` designed to output strings having the type `char *`.

```
    char * const commands = arraymaker(head);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", commands[i]);
    }
```

Pay attention to that using the string literal `"\0"` in this statement

```
argv[++ii] = "\0";
```

does not make a great sense. Instead you could just write

```
argv[++ii] = "";
```

because the string literal `""` is represented in memory like an array with one element `{ '\0' }`. That is it already contains the terminating zero character.

So the function should be declared at least like

```
char ** const arraymaker( const struct Node* head);
```

The data stored in the node should not be changed.

Within the function you need to allocate dynamically an array of pointers that will be returned. And instead of the function `strtok` use function `strspn` and `strcspn` to extract substrings. When for each substring allocate dynamically a character array pointer to which will be stored in the dynamically allocated array of pointers.